# How to package Haskell project for Linux use

Tags: linux, haskell, cross-compiling

This my setup.cabal file :

```
-- Initial SparkSetup.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                SparkSetup
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:            
-- description:         
-- license:             
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              user
maintainer:          user
-- copyright:           
-- category:            
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:  
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable SparkSetup
  -- main-is:             
  -- other-modules:       
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8
  -- hs-source-dirs:      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

When run `cabal build` this generates a SparkSetup.exe file in dist folder which can be executed directly. Is there something similar of Linux ? Can a .sh file be generated which will package the Haskell code to be executed on Linux ?

Update : I'm on Windows and want to cross compile for Linux / Unix

Comment: You're on Windows and want to cross-compile for Linux? Or do you want to know how to package your (on Linux) compiled executable for distribution?

Comment: @Zeta please see update

Comment: This is non-trivial: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation

Comment: @melpomene: That's the old guide. Simon Marlow has posted a new one on https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling.

Comment: @Zeta First sentence in my link: "This page contains the design notes for cross compilation. For instructions on how to actually do it, see [Building/CrossCompiling](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a single binary file that works across all common distributions is a challenging task at best. People like [Joey Hess managed to pull that through](http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/completely_linux_distribution-independent_packaging/), but it is generally not recommended.

One option is to upload your code to [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/), instruct your users to install the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) (which, if you stay compatible with older releases of GHC, is as easy as running `apt-get install haskell-platform` on Debian-based distributions) and then run `cabal install SparkSetup`.

In order to make sure your package builds with a variety of compilers, you can use [Herbert’s excellent travis setup](https://github.com/hvr/multi-ghc-travis), at least as long as your code is on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, a service like travis together with an automatic deploy to the GitHub releases is probably _a lot_ easier than cross-compiling from Windows to Linux. I remember that [cross-compiling to Pi](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9589#comment:8) wasn't easy, and as soon as additional dependencies turn up, [it gets __really__ messy](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3bbp7v/whats_the_current_state_for_crosscompiling/).

Comment: @Zeta thanks for the Pi link, as running on Pi is my eventual intention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distribute something binary that works with minimum hassle almost everywhere and is super-easy to install, you can always use Docker. Also, check [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Docker), they seem to provide quite good support for this type of things.

Comment: Seems like there are some issues with stack+docker on Windows: *"While Docker does support non-Linux operating systems through the boot2docker VM, there are issues with host volume mounting that prevent stack from being usable in this configuration."* So OP needs to use stack in the VM. At that point he's essentially compiling from Linux (VM) to Linux (native).

Comment: @Zeta Hmm, your are right on that. But still you get an easy way to "package" and "distribute" stuff if you use docker, at least for Mac OS X and Linux: you give your users less than 100 bytes in the form of a command line. And total guarantees, or a lot of them at least...